# Is there a threshold or use case that would push an implementation from AWS Athena to Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-athena, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I've seen lots of blogs and posts comparing AWS Athena and Redshift Spectrum. The unanimous consensus seems to be that if you don't already have a Redshift implementation, just go with Athena.

Are there any scenarios or thresholds where Redshift Spectrum would better support a reporting need, and force a switch from Athena to Redshift?

--Update--

I found the following in the Big Data Analytics Options on AWS white paper under the Anti-Patterns section for Athena

> Amazon Redshift is a better tool for Enterprise Reporting and Business Intelligence Workloads involving iceberg queries or cached data at the
>   nodes.

Then is it fair to say that Athena is for data analytics as opposed to business intelligence?

https://www.stitchdata.com/blog/business-intelligence-vs-data-analytics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it comes down to storage. The storage of large amounts of structured data only makes sense in a true data wharehouse setup like Redshift.

Trying to fit the same level of data into flat files like Parquet isn't appropriate.